# Test for Swift package involves reading text file, but says I don't have permissions and fails with 'nil'

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest

I'm relearning programming and teaching myself basic Swift concepts by writing a simple CSV parser as a Swift package as a small project. This involves being able to feed the class an arbitrary file path to read from an external `.cvs` file.
However this fails and the error says I don't have permission to read the file in my unit tests. Is this an issue of `XCTest` doing sandboxing in the same way playgrounds also sandbox? If so, is there any way of letting the sandbox access the file?

Here is the internal code for the function:

```
public func parse(fromFilePath path : String) -> Array<Dictionary<String,String>>?{
    let fileManager = FileManager()
    if let fileContents = fileManager.contents(atPath: path){
        let fileText = fileContents.base64EncodedString()
        
        print(fileText.split(separator: "\n").count)
    }else{
        print("File read failed!")
    }
    //If all fails, fall through to return nil
    return nil
}
```

And here is what the unit test is doing. The first function passes since it's not a proper file path but the second test fails the valid path because of the permissions issue.

```
    func testFileOpen_Failed() throws{
    let parser = CSVParse()
    let results = parser.parse(fromFilePath: "Nonexistent File")
    XCTAssert(results == nil)
}

func testFileOpen_Success() throws{
    let parser = CSVParse()
    let filePath = ".CSVParseTests"
    let results = parser.parse(fromFilePath: filePath)
    XCTAssert(results != nil)
}
```

Comment: First of all I think you should work with URL's instead of string paths in your code and tests and secondly `".CSVParseTests"` is not a proper path in itself. 
If you work with URL's in your code and your test then for a swift package the XCTest framework will use /tmp as its working folder so to create the same url for testing is very simple, `let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "CSVParseTests")`.